# Как создать изображение из html и css средствами php

Tags: php, html, css

Подскажите, как можно реализовать данный вопрос?

Есть html и css код типа:

```html
<div id="id1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <div class="c1 c2">
  <div id="id2">
   <a href="http://st.ru/" title="Текст" target="_blank"><img src="gerb_img.min.svg" alt="Текст" style="float: left;">
   <span class="c3">
    Текст
   </span>
   </a>
  </div>
  <div style="float: right;">
   <div class="c4">
   </div>
   <div class="c5">
   <ul>
    <li><span class="note"></span><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-inverse fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" title="Текст"></i>
     <ul>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

соответственно и стили к данному коду.
как это все преобразовать в картинку?
картинку желательно сохранять на серваке, т.к. все это скриптами выводиться на сторонние сайты
--*--ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ--*--
Если вдруг не очень понятно вышеописанное, то еще раз но другими словами суть задачи:
Php на основе условий формирует html+css код (без вывода на экран), этот код (html+css) надо без использования сторонних ресурсов и без вывода на экран преобразовать в изображение, которое уже в дальнейшем можно будет переслать/вставить куда потребуется.

Все что удалось нарыть в гугле - и близко не отвечаем требованиям.

Comment: Преобразовать в картинку что? Выражайтесь яснее

Comment: По моему уже в вопросе понятно, что и во что надо преобразовать... И дальше так же раскрывается, дано: html и css, требуется: средствами php преобразовать это все в изображение

Comment: Есть извращенский способ. Можно страницу сохранить в pdf с помощью гугл хром. Потом из pdf тащить изображение

Answer (score 0):

По сути вам нужна генерация превью страницы. Средствами самого PHP это сделать очень трудно, но можно обратится к стороннему сервису для генерации превьюшки (http://webresourcesdepot.com/10-free-website-thumbnail-generation-services/)
Так же можно использовать стороннюю утилиту (читай браузера), которая умеет генерить превьюшки и просто запустить ее с PHP например через exec()

Comment: Ресурс где формируется html+css код - закрытый и сторонние сайты/сервисы не смогут пройти по ссылке и сделать скрин (и кстати, будет скрин всего экрана или области где хоть что-то есть? мне нужно чтоб в изображением было только то, что отображает код из примера, все остальное не должно присутствовать в изображении).  Может знаете и подскажите рабочий способ чтоб все на стороне моего сервера происходило?

Comment: Вот есть такой инструмент https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ который из PHP можно запускать через exec()